# Mapbox / Javascript: Implementing hover and clicked state

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to allow my Mapbox zones to have both clicked and hover states. Once something has been clicked I want that to persist, stay in that state, even if I then hover on another tile.

In implementing it though, what happens is when I click it turns to the clicked state, but moving my mouse on that area or another tile changes it from clicked back to hover.

Here is a demo of this: https://codepen.io/hiven/pen/zYPbRNK

The key bit of code is here:

```
     if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
        map.setFeatureState(
           { source: "states", id: hoveredStateId },
           { mystate: null }
        );
     }
     if (hoveredStateId !== 2) {
     hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
     map.setFeatureState(
        { source: "states", id: hoveredStateId },
        { mystate: 1 }
     );
     }
```

The state 1 is hover, state 2 is clicked. With this code I thought it would only set the state to hover if the tile is not at clicked state (2) already. However this doesn't seem to work, as moving your mouse on a clicked tile changes it to hover state.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include quite enough code above. The key bit of code is actually this:

```
map.on('mousemove', 'state-fills', (e) => {
              if (e.features.length > 0) {
                  if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
                      map.setFeatureState({
                          source: "states",
                          id: hoveredStateId
                      }, {
                          mystate: null
                      });
                  }
```

It says: when the mouse moves over anything, clear the current state.

Also, this is clearly wrong:

```
     if (hoveredStateId !== 2) {
```

You seem to have confused the *state* (null, 1 or 2) with the *id* of the feature (any number 0 or greater).

Comment: Thank you much for this. So, reviewing this advice, do I still want to keep this snippet of code so if does clear the current state on mouse move, but add a condition to not do this if mystate is equal to 2?

Comment: I tried to implement this a few times on line 68 here https://codepen.io/hiven/pen/zYPbRNK?editors=0011 but I can't get it to work, the hover on the same item still cancels the clicked state